# android select string by date month and day

Tags: java, android, string, date

in string.xml i have added some string like this

```
<string name="m8d1">text sample</string>
<string name="m8d2">text sample</string>
<string name="m8d3">text sample</string>
```

and i have widget i want to show string by date month and day widget code

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) { 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 

        String txt = context.getString(R.string.m"+month+"d"+day);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettext,txt);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the meaning of `R.string.m` in depth.
You won't be able to do something like

```
String txt = context.getString(R.string.m"+month+"d"+day);
```

Explaining in detail-
The R file contains a static class `string` and `string` class contains a static integer member `m`. There is nothing like key value pair so you can not access that by string.

**Edit**
You can use this method to get the value using an string-

```
private String getStringResourceByName(Context context,String name) { 
      int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getPackageName());
      return context.getString(resId);
    }
```

So now you will be able to have something like-

```
String txt = getStringResourceByName(context,"m"+month+"d"+day);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you

```
String txt="m"+month+"d"+day;  
txt=context.getResources().getString(context.getResources().getIdentifier(txt, "string", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use

```
String txt = context.getResource().getString(R.string.m)+month+"d"+day;
```

Comment: It is context. getResources().getString(R.string. m8d1)+month+"d"+day;

Comment: what is error in the formulation code.The line of code working fine with me.